# Java Layout Insets

Tags: java, gridbaglayout, insets

[board image](http://img101.imageshack.us/img101/236/boardt.jpg)

the above is a board layout done by using gridbaglayout.

i would like insets of 5 pixels around the whole board but not between each label.

i scaned the api and havent come up with something that lets me do this.

does this mean i have to nest my board gui inside another gridbaglayout with the insets desired?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add an empty border to the containing component